# java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo. I need to generate AttestedKeyPair with DevicePolicyManager

Tags: java, android, android-source, android-11

2022-10-13 11:04:56.584 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.example.devicepolicy/com.example.devicepolicy.MainActivity}
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2374)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2358)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2341)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2283)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.generateKeyPair(IDevicePolicyManager.java:9432)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.generateKeyPair(DevicePolicyManager.java:5367)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at com.example.devicepolicy.MainActivity.generateKeyAndCheckAttestation(MainActivity.java:105)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at com.example.devicepolicy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.585 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3607)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2078)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7721)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.586 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err: Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
2022-10-13 11:04:56.587 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminWithPolicyForUidLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3409)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.587 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminOrCheckPermissionForCallerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3292)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.587 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminForCallerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3273)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.587 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.enforceCanManageScopeOrCheckPermission(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:7049)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.587 8859-8859/com.example.devicepolicy W/System.err:     at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.enforceCanManageScope(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:7035)
2022-10-13 11:04:56.687 8859-8899/com.example.devicepolicy I/AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : 015159c22, Idb46f6465a

Comment: mDevicePolicyManager =
                    (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            
            KeyGenParameterSpec spec = specBuilder.build();
            @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "LocalSuppress"})
            AttestedKeyPair generated;
            generated = mDevicePolicyManager.generateKeyPair(
                            getWho(),
                            keyAlgorithm,
                            spec,
                            deviceIdAttestationFlags);

Comment: it would be nice if you could add more info to your question since it is just many lines of logs and also you can not put them in code block.